# Extract OTP Key using regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed, google-authenticator

I have a script that enables OTP / Google Auth via SSH keys and OTP on linux systems. Once OTP is enabled I send the user a SMS with an otpauth URL. I need to extract the ( normally 16 digit key ) from the otpauth URL.

If they want a visible QR code, an example of the URL is below:

```
https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/user@host.com%3Fsecret%3DWFHGHUFAUYXZFA44%26issuer%3DCOMPANY
```

If they want an otpauth url they can click on to import into a Token / Password Manager, I use the following:

```
otpauth://totp/user@host.com%3Fsecret%3DWFHGHUFAUYXZFA44%26issuer%3DCOMPANY
```

How can I extract the Secret Key from the URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep -oP`:

```
url='https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/user@host.com%3Fsecret%3DWFHGHUFAUYXZFA44%26issuer%3DCOMPANY'

grep -ioP '[?&]chl=.+?%3Fsecret%3D\K[^%]+' <<< "$url"
WFHGHUFAUYXZFA44
```

Comment: Thats great for filtering down to the otpauth url. But, I need the secret key only.

Comment: So you want `%3Fsecret%3DWFHGHUFAUYXZFA44%26issuer%3DCOMPANY` only?

Comment: I would want only the secret key: DWFHGHUFAUYXZFA4

Answer (score 1):

`secret%3D(.*?)(?=%|$)` will find 'secret', the `%3D`, then the number up until it reaches the end of the line or another `%` character.

[Regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/zT6gK6/1)